# Notepad++ replace lines containing 6 digits and word

Tags: regex, notepad++

So i got this:

```
123456asdsa
444444dfsdsdg
3443fsdfdsd
77gdsggfgf
```

and i only wish to delete any lines that contain 6 digits no matter word count so it can be like this:

```
3443fsdfdsd
77gdsggfgf
```

the only thing i found out is this regexp [0-9]{6} which makes me select only the 6 digits but with no words so what should i do?
thank you

Comment: Use `.*[0-9]{6}.*\R?` if the 6 digits can appear anywhere in the string. If you mean the digits should appear at the start of a line, use `^[0-9]{6}.*\R?`

Comment: Do you wish so select the lines with 6 digits or to delete the lines with six digits?

Comment: @Onyambu Question says `i only wish to delete any lines that contain 6 digits`

Comment: If the line contains more than 6 digits in a row, such as 7 or 8 in a row, should it be deleted as well?

Comment: what about `1ab2cd3456efg`  do you want it to be deleted too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?=\w*\d{6})\S+\s
```

Lookahead in that line for 6 digits, then replace that line and the following newline with the empty string:

https://regex101.com/r/mz0vMY/2

Comment: This regex will delete lines will select lines with more than 6 digits and that should not be the case

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
^\D*\d{6}(?!\d).* #or ^\D*\d{6}(?=\D).*
```

In this case, you will see whether there is any non-digits before the digits. When you get six digits, ensure the next is a non-digit. ie only select lines with 6 digits. Those with 7 digits or more or those with less than 6 digits are not selected:

[regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TeN5Kk/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not very clear so I am giving you several alternatives, which I hope one of them fits your need.

If you want to select lines containing 6 consecutive digits and no other digits, you can use

```
^\D*\d{6}\D*$

^                      start of line
 \D*                   some optional non-digit, 
    \d{6}              followed by 6 digits, 
         \D*           followed by some optional non-digit 
            $          till end of line
```

If you want to select lines containing 6 digits (not necessary to be consecutive), you can use this

```
^(\D*\d){6}\D*$


^                       start of line
 (\D*\d)                group of optional non-digit then 1 digit
        {6}             above group happening for 6 times 
                            (i.e. 6 digits in total)
           \D*$         follow by non-digits till end of line
```

If you want to select lines containing a sequence of exactly 6 digits, you can

```
^.*(\b|\D)\d{6}(\b|\D).*$

^.*                              start of line, followed by some chars
   (\b|\D)                       followed word boundary or non-digit
          \d{6}                  6 digits
               (\b|\D)           followed word boundary or non-digit
                      .*$        followed by some chars till end of line
```

---

Update:

With info from @WiktorStribiżew, Notepad++ may be handling `\D` in unexpected way as it may match newlines.  You can simply replace the `\D` in above regex to `[^0-9\n\r]` for preferred behavior.

Comment: just a note, for better performance, you could replace the use of group `( ... )` with a non-capturing group `(?: ... )`

Comment: Not my downvote, but this solution is wrong because `\D` may match a line break and remove more than just 1 line with digits in it.

Comment: Oh I was not paying attention to it being for Notepad++.  Well, that's strange that everyone else is using `\D \S` which is suffering from same problem though, dunno why I am the only one being downvoted :P   Anyway, for a easy fix for Notepad++, simply replace `\D` with `[^0-9\n\r]`  should do the work